# Angular elements custom element displays, but not other components in project

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I am trying to use Angular Elements to migrate from AngularJS and had an AE custom component working, I did a merge and it stops working.

The custom element gets loaded and I can see the text from it, however, I don't see any of my angular components or angular material components.  The constructor and ngOnInit both fires.  So It can't seem to find either my components or angular material.

app.module.ts

```
import { D6LargeMenuItemComponent } from "./component/d6-large-menu-item/d6-large-menu-item.component";
import { LargeMenuComponent } from "./component/large-menu/large-menu.component";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
} from "@angular/material";

import { createCustomElement } from "@angular/elements";
import { D6OrderComponent } from "./component/d6-order/d6-order.component";

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        D6OrderComponent,
        LargeMenuComponent,
        D6LargeMenuItemComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule
      ],
      entryComponents: [D6OrderComponent],
      providers: []

      // bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
      constructor(injector: Injector) {
        const d6Order = createCustomElement(D6OrderComponent, { injector });
        customElements.define('d6-order', d6Order);
      }
      ngDoBootstrap() { }
    }
```

d6-order.companent.html

```
<div>
  <!-- this shows up -->
  d6-large menu 4
  <!-- this shows up -->
  <button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
  <!-- this shows up -->
    <button>dumb button</button>

  <d6-large-menu [itemList]='itemList'></d6-large-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a null injection (Location) error in one of the components.